# Nokogiri XSD Schema validation with remote includes, possible?

Tags: ruby, xsd, nokogiri

I've got this `schema.xsd` file:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="http://raw.githubusercontent.com/zerocracy/datum/0.16/xsd/pmo/types.xsd"/>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm loading it with Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'
Nokogiri::XML::Schema(File.open('schema.xsd'))
```

I'm getting:

```
Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}include': 
Failed to load the document 'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/zerocracy/datum/0.16/xsd/pmo/types.xsd' for inclusion.
```

Is there any change to make it work?

Comment: Is the include actually for `example.com`, or is that place-holder you've use for your question?

Comment: @MathiasMüller There definitely cannot be, [`example.com` is reserved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com).

Comment: Of course `example.com` is a placeholder. In real example there is a real URL with another XSD document available.

Comment: (Deleted my previous comments as they were false leads.) Without a real URL it is hard to reproduce your issue. Are there namespaces in the remote or local schema?

Comment: @MathiasMüller I updated my question, now it contains the real URI

Comment: Thanks, now a perfectly fine question. Did you see [this](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/191)?

Comment: @MathiasMüller yes, but it doesn't help. They are talking about local files, not remote ones, like in my example.

Comment: I think this may be due to libxml not supporting ssl connections (Github redirects the request to https). When I test with the file on a local http server your code works without errors.

Comment: @matt I believe you're right, that's exactly the problem I'm having. Feel free to submit an answer, I will accept it.